# Join in SQL statement

Tags: sql, join

I tried to retrieve values from 2 tables (main (accounts), sub(account_Details)), which they are:
acc_ID,acc_Name,acc_Place,acc_Date, total "total of debts-payment-returned".
and i do it like this is below, but an error appear:
"You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression *acc_Name* as part of an aggregate function. "

The Code:

```
select a.acc_ID,a.acc_Name,a.acc_Place,a.acc_Date,
       sum(b.acc_Sub_Debt)-sum(b.acc_Sub_Payment)+sum(b.acc_Sub_Returned) total 
from accounts a,account_Details b 
where a.acc_ID = b.acc_Sub_ID and total < 1000  
group by a.acc_ID order by a.acc_ID asc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting bunch of `non aggregate` columns and you have added only only one column in `group by`.

Add all the `non aggregate` columns in `group by`

```
select a.acc_ID,a.acc_Name,a.acc_Place,a.acc_Date,
       sum(b.acc_Sub_Debt)-sum(b.acc_Sub_Payment)+sum(b.acc_Sub_Returned) total 
from accounts a,account_Details b 
where a.acc_ID = b.acc_Sub_ID and total < 1000  
group by a.acc_ID,a.acc_Name,a.acc_Place,a.acc_Date
order by a.acc_ID asc
```